# Having troubles creating a specific TRIGGER in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger, phpmyadmin

So I am trying to implement a trigger in MySQL that is triggered once a new user is registered. 
The relation of my tables are:
**USER_ACCOUNTS** has *primary key* **USER_ID**.
**RACE_TRACKS** has *primary key* **RACETRACK_ID**.
**HIGHSCORES** has as *foreign_keys* **USER_ID** and **RACETRACK_ID**.

The trigger I am trying make, must create records in HIGHSCORES table in a way that each NEW.USER_ID has a record for each of the RACE TRACKS (RACETRACK_ID).

Using phpMyAdmin database management tool I came to this point.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE trackID INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE trackCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT USER_ID FROM INSERTED WHERE USER_ID = NEW.USER_ID;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES SELECT trackID FROM RACE_TRACK;

OPEN trackCURSOR;
    REPEAT
    FETCH trackCURSOR INTO trackID;
    IF NOT done THEN
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES (RACETRACK_ID, USER_ID)
            VALUES (trackID, NEW.USER_ID);
            END;
    END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE trackCURSOR;
END;
```

I am not getting any errors but when I am testing it if it works nothing happens. I am a bit confused to say the least because I do not have experience with triggers. If there is any way to enlighten me I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
After some feedback more searching this is how my trigger looks now.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_RACETRACKID INT;
DECLARE FINISHED INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE racetrackCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT RACETRACK_ID FROM RACETRACK;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = TRUE;

OPEN racetrackCURSOR;

get_racetrackID : LOOP
    FETCH racetrackCURSOR INTO v_RACETRACKID;
    IF FINISHED = TRUE THEN
          LEAVE get_racetrackID;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES (RACETRACK_ID, BEST_LAP, BEST_RACETIME_1, 
        BEST_RACETIME_2,USER_ID) VALUES (v_RACETRACKID,null,null,null 
        ,NEW.USER_ID);
    END LOOP get_racetrackID;
    CLOSE

 END;
```

Comment: MySQL have no INSERTED pseudo-table. It has NEW pseudo-table, which contains **one** record (trigger in MySQL have FOR EACH ROW type).

Comment: hi @Akina thanks for your quick response. I changed INSERTED TO    => FROM USER_ACCOUNT WHERE USER_ID = NEW.USER_ID; but why do i need FOR EACH ROW type? should i use it in the loop? before BEGIN ?

Comment: [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: Ouch! a cursor in a trigger?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your code in a CREATE TRIGGER statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddNewUserToHighscoresTable 
    AFTER INSERT ON USER_ACCOUNTS 
    BEGIN 
         <insert code to run after inserts on the USER_ACCOUNTS table here...> 
    END
```

Comment: i don't think it required when you do it through phpMyAdmin. it auto generate that piece of code.

Comment: The query text is syntactically incorrect. Look carefully - the question is [mysql]-tagged.

Comment: @PanagiotisDelphini *it auto generate that piece of code* Do NOT allow any auto-generation. This is a potential point of error.

Comment: Sorry about that mistake i actually fixed few things now can you please check the my first post and give me feedback? thanks!

Comment: I found the issue it was a misspell of a table. In my EDIT is the actual solution.